# Не выполнять анимацию при переходе между страницами сайта

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть простенькая анимация на css. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы она срабатывала только при открытии сайта и обновлении страницы, но не срабатывала когда совершается переход между страницами моего многостраничного сайта.

```css
@keyframes slideInFromTop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animated-element {
  animation: slideInFromTop 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h1 class=animated-element>Hi!</h1>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ***animation-fill-mode: none | forwards | backwards | both***

Comment: @Air, вопрос обновлён. Оказывается, он интереснее, чем казалось)

Comment: как вариант - отказаться от обычных переходов в пользу подзагрузки данных, к примеру на том же ajax :3 для пары учебных станичек это конечно как из пушки по воробьям. если судить по сложности анимации в вопросе, вам может хватить и таргетования ссылок в `<iframe>`, но если сайт действительно массивный, ajax уже не будет лишним.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я когда писал коммент, вопрос вообще по другому звучал. Кстати привет, 100 лет....)) Вопрос  и в прям  интересны. Сходу и не соображу, как реализовать.  Ответ ниже еще не читал...

Comment: @Air, да я вначале тоже подумал как и ты, а потом мне в комменте сюрприз подкинули)))

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это поможет (в сниппете не работает из-за настроек безопасности):

```js
if (document.referer != null && !document.referer.startsWith(location.origin)) {
  document.querySelector('.animated-element').classList.remove('animated-element')
}
```

```css
@keyframes slideInFromTop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animated-element {
  animation: slideInFromTop 1s ease-out both 1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class=animated-element>Hi!</h1>
```

Comment: ваш код не работает как я бы хотел. <img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" style="animation: slideInFromTop 1s ease-out both 1;"> он выполняется при переходе между страницами. возможно проблема в том, что js и css в одном файле с html?

Comment: @Никита, ого. А не кажется, что в вопросе надо было сказать, что тебе требуется обрабатывать переход между разными страницами? В этом видео может содержаться то, что поможет получить желаемый результат, если это вообще возможно: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkML640BcoA.

Comment: @Никита, я исправил ответ - возможно, это поможет. Ща ещё и вопрос исправлю.

Comment: если вам не сложно, напишите мне в телеграм - https://t.me/wArahhh

Comment: @Никита, зачем бы мне было надо писать в телеграм?

Comment: у меня ничего не получается. я 1  в 1 все скопировал. в js я 0 поэтому сам ничего поправить не смогу. тут не очень удобно общаться и опять же - если вам не сложно